# Solve the differential equation $ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2y^2$, which passes through point $(1, -1)$. What is $y$ when $x = 3$? Please find my error.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation $ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 2y^2$, which passes through point $(1, -1)$. What is $y$ when $x = 3$?

My reasoning is as follows.

$ \dfrac{dy}{y^2} = 2 dx$

$ \Rightarrow \displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{y^2} dy = \int 2 dx $

$ \Rightarrow \displaystyle\int y^{-2} dy = \int 2 dx $

$ \Rightarrow -y^{-1} + C = 2x + C$

$ \Rightarrow -y = \dfrac{1}{2x + C}$

The constant for the particular differential equation passing through (1, -1):

$ \Rightarrow 1 = \dfrac{1}{2 + C} $

$ \Rightarrow 2 + C = 1 $

$ \Rightarrow C = -1 $

**HOWEVER**, I am told that $C = 1$. Where did I make an error?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't. it is correct $C=-1$.take off $C$ from an equation above.

Comment: What you have is the equation $y = (-1) \cdot (2x + c)^{-1}$. When $(y,x) = (1,-1)$ the result is $c=1$.

Comment: I see now. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Perhaps the model solution was integrating $\int (-1/y^2)dy=-2x+C$, which would give the sign flip. Anyway, the interesting control value is $y(3)$ which should be independent of how the constant was defined.